# SSRS -Query Designer is automatically changing my query

Tags: reporting-services

I have a query in SSRS query designer with AND and OR  ,when i execute SQL the query changes to a totally different query

The query is shown below,the last parameter SIDSCD can be blank or entered as a parameter

````
     SELECT SCFRAN, SCDPCD, SCMOCD, STMOYR, STCHCD, STMGCD, SCVIN, 
     SCINDT, INVDATE, INVMONTH, INVYEAR, SISMCD, SIDSCD, SIDSC1, SICUNM, 
     SICUCD, SCMGCD, 
                      NSP, WEMEMNL, CDDESL
FROM            VEHICLE.VHVPRICOM2
WHERE        SCFRAN = ? AND STMOYR = ? AND STMGCD = ? AND STCHCD = ? AND SCMOCD = ? AND SISMCD = ? AND (SIDSCD = ? OR ? ='') ```

But the Query designer changes the query to this when i execute SQL


```SELECT        SCFRAN, SCDPCD, SCMOCD, STMOYR, STCHCD, STMGCD, SCVIN, SCINDT, INVDATE, INVMONTH, INVYEAR, SISMCD, SIDSCD, SIDSC1, SICUNM, SICUCD, SCMGCD, 
                      NSP, WEMEMNL, CDDESL
FROM            VEHICLE.VHVPRICOM2
WHERE        (SCFRAN = ?) AND (STMOYR = ?) AND (STMGCD = ?) AND (STCHCD = ?) AND (SCMOCD = ?) AND (SISMCD = ?) AND (SIDSCD = ?) OR
                      (SCFRAN = ?) AND (STMOYR = ?) AND (STMGCD = ?) AND (STCHCD = ?) AND (SCMOCD = ?) AND (SISMCD = ?) AND (? = '')```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way to deal with the problem i mentioned .Its a bit longer process ,but it is working

1)In Report Data ,create DataSource ( i was using shared DataSource)

2)In Report Data,create a Dataset and select option "use embedded dataset in my report"

3)In the place to write query ,

Take only the select query i.e'

````
 SELECT  SCFRAN, SCDPCD, SCMOCD, STMOYR, STCHCD, STMGCD, SCVIN, SCINDT, INVDATE, 
    INVMONTH, INVYEAR, SISMCD, SIDSCD, SIDSC1, SICUNM, SICUCD, SCMGCD, 
                         NSP, WEMEMNL, CDDESL, MMMODS, SCSLTY, SCINPX, SCINNO
FROM            VEHICLE.VHVPRICOM2 ```


Now Click on the button refresh fields ,with this you will get the fields in dataset and you can see them in the fields tab.Otherwise you will have to manually add them in fields tab 

4)
="SELECT        SCFRAN, SCDPCD, SCMOCD, STMOYR, STCHCD, STMGCD, SCVIN, SCINDT, INVDATE, INVMONTH, INVYEAR, SISMCD, SIDSCD, SIDSC1, SICUNM, SICUCD, SCMGCD," & 
"                         NSP, WEMEMNL, CDDESL, MMMODS, SCSLTY, SCINPX, SCINNO FROM VEHICLE.VHVPRICOM2 " &
" WHERE        (SCFRAN = '" & Parameters!PRFranchise.Value & "') AND (STMGCD = '" & Parameters!PRModelGroup.Value & "') AND (SCMOCD = '" & Parameters!PRModelCode.Value & "') AND (SISMCD IN " &
"                             (SELECT        WEMEMCD " &
"                               FROM            VEHICLE.VHTEMPL VHTEMPL_1 " &
"                               WHERE        (WEMEMCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMTLCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMGLCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMBHCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMTCMCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMGCMCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMBCMCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMHOTLCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMHOGLCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMHHODCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "') OR " &
"                                                         (WEMGHODCD = '" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "'))) AND (SIDSCD = '" & Parameters!PRDestination.Value & "' OR " &
"                         '" & Parameters!PRDestination.Value & "' ='') AND (CHAR(INVYEAR) = '"& Parameters!PRInvYear.Value &"' OR '"& Parameters!PRInvYear.Value &"' ='') AND (CHAR(STMOYR) = '" & Parameters!PRModelYear.Value &"') AND (STCHCD = '" &Parameters!PRCharCode.Value &"') "

Now click on f(x) and paste your code ,my sample is as above .There are things to be done like first starting letter should be = ,every line must be in " " and ended with &

5) Instead of ? in shared data set ,you can add Parameters in place of the ? like this
'" & Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value & "'

If we do through f(x) ,the query is not automatically changed and we get our result as we wanted
````